# Hilbert's Inequality - improved???

Tags: inequality, reference-request

Assume for convenience that $a_n\ge0$ (this also clarifies why certain inequalities below are in fact stronger than certain other inequalities below). Of the various inequalities Hilbert proved, I'm talking about the one that's  often stated $$\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty\frac{a_na_m}{n+m}\le\pi\sum|a_n|^2.$$ This is the same as $$\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty\frac{a_na_m}{n+m+2}\le\pi\sum|a_n|^2.\quad(1)$$

I believe I've seen the stronger version $$\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty\frac{a_na_m}{n+m+1}\le\pi\sum|a_n|^2\quad(2)$$once or twice.
I recently stumbled upon a proof of a yet stronger version:
$$\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty\frac{a_na_m}{n+m+1/2}\le\pi\sum|a_n|^2.\quad(3)$$

The question is whether (3) is well known (or just known, heh).

On the one hand it seems unlikely that (3) could be new, since Hilbert's inequality has been studied for a long time and the proof is not that hard. On the other hand if (3) is known then why do people cite (2)?

(My work so far: Oh gimme a break. I've looked. It's impossible to know that what you're looking for does not exist in the places you haven't looked, and there are just too many places it could be hiding...)

Comment: (2) looks like H_0 from here http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/jameson/hilbert.pdf to me. No idea for (3), too lazy.

Comment: The author in [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vSgmBjpA-24C&lpg=PA1&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q&f=false) refers to Ingham .. eqn (1.1.16) on page 2.

Comment: @r9m (+1) *eqn (1.1.15)